# How to implement OAuth and OAuth2 in web app?

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-native-app, tizen-web-simulator

I'm struggling with implementing OAuth mechanism in web app. I have seen a lot of topics about it but no one gives a definitely answer how to do it. Basically I tried two ways to achieve it.

1. Create hybrid app and use official tizen API.
   Service app can't access UI elements like web view so we can't perform it in that way.
2. Implement on the client side using windows.
   I read some posts that this solution works on emulator but it doesn't work on real device. Unfortunately I don't have a Tizen phone so I can't check it. Can somebody confirm that? I can also add that this way doesn't work on web simulator. Ripple doesn't show us a window.open(...) page

Does anybody implemented it? Do you have any ideas how can I do it?

Some other topics on tizen developers forum:

https://developer.tizen.org/forums/web-application-development/oauth-issues

https://developer.tizen.org/forums/web-application-development/implementing-oauth-mobile-app

Answer (score 0):

You may take a Look at Tizen App Control API. App Control API provides several ways to Launch another app.

[App Control API Guide](https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/api-guides/native-application/application-framework/application/app-control?langredirect=1)

[Tip & Tech. : Application API Guide](https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/application-api-guide)